# Qlik Sense: Join data from MySQL and Oracle

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

The MySQL stores the status and the Oracle stores the date. I want to join them but I'm not sure how and this is not working:

```
<CONNECT TO DB_MYSQL>
FROM_MYSQL:
Sql
SELECT checkno AS "Check Number", status FROM checks;

<CONNECT TO DB_ORACLE>
JOIN
FROM_ORACLE:
Sql
SELECT check_no AS "Check Number", check_date FROM checks;
```

Should I store each on their own QVDs first and then join them?
I want to make a QVD where they are already combined so if I store each of them on their own QVD then I will have 3 QVDs in total. I only want 1, the combined one.

Comment: Think that your script looks ok. What is not working for you?